# Drive.Permissions.insert fails with incomplete error message

Tags: google-apps-script, google-drive-api

This is my 1st attempt at using the Google API's and I'm having a bit of a problem suppressing the email notification
I have the following code that receives the following error message when executing `Drive.Permissions.insert`
The message I am getting is:

> API call to drive.permissions.insert failed with error: Required

I added the Try/Catch to see if I could get more than the abbreviated error message but even that truncates the full error message.

```
function shareFoldersWithGroup() {
    var groupEmail;
    var permissionResource = {
        role: 'writer',
        type: 'group',
        value: 'groupEmail'
    };
    var optionalArgs = {
        'sendNotificationEmails': 'false'
    };
    var folders = DriveApp.getFolders();
    groupEmail = "test4236@something.com"; // Replace with the actual group email
    while (folders.hasNext()) {
        var folder = folders.next();
        Logger.log(folder.getName());
        try {
            Drive.Permissions.insert(permissionResource, folder, optionalArgs);
        } catch (err) {
            Logger.log(err.message);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Drive.Permissions.insert(permissionResource, folder, optionalArgs)
```

`folder` is of type `Folder`:

```
var folder = folders.next();
```

Whereas it should be the `id` of the folder as written in the [doc](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/reference/rest/v3/permissions/create). It should be

```
Drive.Permissions.insert(permissionResource, folder.getId(), optionalArgs);
```